# How to adapt this locator for iOS is for automated testing

Tags: java, appium-ios

`nameProduct` is the parameter that the actor has, this locator works for Android but I want to adapt it for iOS so that they work in the same project.

```
String locator = String.format("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
                  .scrollable(true)
                  .instance(0))
                  .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector()
                  .textContains(\"%s\").instance(0))", nameProduct)
                  .locatedForAndroid(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(locator));
```

But I don't know if it works for iOS so for the moment it doesn't locate me.

```
 String iosLocator = String.format("type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' AND label CONTAINS '%s'",
                                            nameProduct);
 .locatedForIOS(AppiumBy.iOSClassChain(iosLocator));
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA